# Com qual linguagem web eu poderia desenvolver algo parecido com essa imagem?

Tags: php, html, css, javascript-eventos

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Bom estou querendo implementar algum sistema desses em um site, 
como mostrado na imagem vc escolhe onde vc está e onde vc quer chegar e o modo e aparece um valor,
alguém poderiam e dar uma luz?
Qual linguagem usar ou algum code parecido ou algo q eu possa estudar?

Comment: Não sei por que a pergunta,você mesmo a respondeu através das Tags

Comment: mas tem como fazer só com uma linguagem ou teria q usar as 3?

Comment: Tem como fazer algo no mesmo nivel só com html e css?

Comment: Você teria que ter um Backend para salvar as opções do Usuário e mostrar o preço de acordo com a seleção.isso seria feito com o PHP,para estilizar você usaria css.Javascript não é necessariamente obrigatório,da pra fazer sem.

Comment: Obrigado mano vou tentar dar uma estudada nisso para tentar fazer então eu procuro por videos ou algo no google com relação a backend e salvar em php? vc teria algo relacionado ao tema pra me passar ?

Comment: e responde o topico para q eu possa votar no seu comentario .

Comment: tranquilo mano.

Comment: Gabriel, quando vc achar que uma resposta é útil e respondeu a sua pergunta, não deve "apenas" votar nela, é importante marcar a resposta com ✓, conforme descrito na página de [Tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) do site. Marcando ✓ na resposta que vc considerou suficientemente útil e que respondeu a sua pergunta, vc está recompensando adequadamente o autor da resposta e motivando outros a responderem, além de futuramente poder estar ajudando outros que tiverem a mesma dúvida da sua pergunta. Abs!

Comment: Estude bastante e não desista. É complicado quando está iniciando, surgem muitas dúvidas. Mas com o tempo e muitos videos tutoriais e muita prática, você vai chegar lá!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Para fazer um sistema assim Você precisará de:

- PHP: Será utilizado para guardar as opções do usuário em um banco de 
  dados e gerar o cálculo do preço baseado em quais opções ele escolheu
- CSS: para estilizar a página de acordo com o seu layout.
- javascript: Depois que o usuário escolhesse as opções,você tem 2
  opções,atualizar a página com o valor total ou usar javascript para
  atualizar o valor sem precisar atualizar a página.

  Como você está começando,recomendo que inicie passo a passo. Primeiro
  escreva o código mais simples. Crie a sua página com HTML e css,do
  jeito que você quer. Após isso pesquise sobre PHP e mysqli.(não
  adianta mostrar tudo isso se não salvar os dados) Com isso acima,já
  da pra fazer.Depois que você pegar mais experiência e tiver menos
  dificuldade,você já adiciona Javascript para tornar mais dinâmica a
  página.

Comment: opa mano vlw mesmo, eu já fiz todo o html e css da pagina vou começar a estudar sobre php e mysqli agora.

Comment: Qualquer dúvida ou dificuldade é so chamar .

Comment: opa mano vlw, você recomendaria algum site p estudo ou algum curso ou canal ?

Comment: Recomendo essa playlist:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F7KzJ7e6EAc&list=PLHz_AreHm4dm4beCCCmW4xwpmLf6EHY9k